# Why does rig work only on one side of the mesh?

Tags: rigging

I've rigged everything fine, it looks good, it feels good, everything is good. The rig works, but when I try to use the rig, the right side of the rig doesn't work. [image]

and when I try to use the left side....

[image]

Everything is good! I still had the mirror modifier so I thought that was the problem, but I've applied it and nothing still works. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several conditions have to be fulfilled to make automatic vertex group weight mirroring work:

- bone names are correctly formatted, usually suffixed by `.L` or `.R`, respectively.
- vertex groups for both sides exist on your mesh - these may be empty, but must exist for the mirrored side too. First <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> select the mesh, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> select the armature > <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Armature Deform* > *With Empty Groups*.
- vertex groups must be enabled on the Mirror modifier, but they already are by default
- make sure the mirror modifier comes before the armature modifier